# Recargar componente al volver a llamarlo con distintos parámetros

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

Quisiera saber si alguien me puede instruir acerca de la manera correcta para recargar un componente en angular.

Mi situación es la siguiente tengo las siguiente ruta en el:

"app-routing.module.ts"

```
 const routes: Routes = [
 {path: 'reporte/horarios/:horario',
  component: HorariosComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard] }]
```

Mi problema es que si yo estoy por ejemplo en la ruta:

> /reporte/horarios/aula

y quisiera ir de manera directa sin pasar por ningún segundo componente a a la ruta

> /reporte/horarios/docente

donde solo cambió el valor de la variable  **:horario** el componente no se recarga sino que se mantiene el mismo que ya estaba cargado.

Mi problema es que en el componente tengo 3 reportes distintos que se muestran según el valor del **:horario** y al no recargarse se me mantiene el mismo reporte que quizá no sea el que yo quiera para llamar a los componentes lo hago de la siguiente manera desde un html

```
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="close()" routerLink="/reporte/horarios/grupo">Grupo</button>
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="close()" routerLink="/reporte/horarios/aula">Aula</button>
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="close()" routerLink="/reporte/horarios/anyo">Año</button>
```

Comment: Seguramente el problema está en cómo obtienes el valor de la variable `horario`, pero si no muestras tu código es complicado asegurarlo. Te aconsejo que añadas el código de tu componente (al menos el código del método `gnOnInit`) para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @PabloLozano Muchas gracias, en el enlace que pusiste estaba la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que una buena opción sea utilizar las rutas hijas o children provistas por angular. En este caso tendrías algo de este estilo:

```
{ path: 'reporte/horarios', component:  HorariosComponent,
children: [
  { path: 'grupo', component: GrupoComponent},
  { path: 'aula', component: AulaComponent},
  { path: 'anyo', component: AnyoComponent}
]
}
```

Puede que orientarlo de esta manera resulte más escablable de cara al futuro y más sencillo de mantener ya que tendrías componentes hijos totalmente modulares e inpedendientes. No sé si te servirá, pero creo que sería una buena manera de plantear el problema al que te enfrentas.

**PD**: en este enlace puedes encontrar un tutorial detallado de como utilizar este tipo de rutas [link](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/routing/child_routes)

Comment: muchas gracias por comentar amigo y darme esa información que desconocía..  pero mi pregunta estaba duplicada y ya tenia solución muchas gracias